# Codeigniter send html mail

Tags: html, codeigniter, sendmail

I know - there are already discussions concerning this, but they all didn't help.

All I want is to send a simple html mail - with:

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('me@myadress.de', 'My name');
    $this->email->to('me@home.de');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('test'); # for test only - normally I load a html view
    $this->email->send();
```

Works fine with the default configuration (`$config['mailtype'] = 'text';`), but when I change it to `$config['mailtype'] = 'html';` - I just get

*Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.*

The only answers I found was to use SMPT - but I would prefer a solution using sendmail. (I'm pretty sure sendmails supports html mails. ^^)

Any other hints? I've no idea how to debug this... the email-print looks ok to me.

Comment: Are you sure you can't find a solution? I see a hell of a lot of links on the related section...

Comment: @Petra How do you `initialize` the `config` ? I mean where do you call it?

Comment: I've an email.php in the config folder.... and it is included.. as it fails, when I change the type to html there. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an html as a email, please check the below controller file

```
class Mail extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}


    public function index()
{       
    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'tls://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*********',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com');

    $this->email->to("yyyy@gmail.com");

    $this->email->subject('Test Email');

    $body = $this->load->view('welcome_message',null,TRUE);

    $this->email->message($body);

    if (!$this->email->send()){
        echo 'fail to load email';
    }
    else {
        echo 'success to send email';
    }
}
```

}

Where `welcome_message` is the html view file which you want to send as a mail body

Comment: So the only solution is to use SMTP??

Comment: may i talk to you personally

Comment: may i talk to you on gmail